# Conflict btw two mootools version files

Tags: mootools, conflict

I have one videobox that acts like a lightbox for displaying video using mootools.js file and I am trying to integrate in my web page a menu using mootools-1.2.1-core-nc.js. Is there any way to make this files work togethere without conflicting???

Answer (score 1):

Dimitar thats not true. Mootools always release a compatability layer between different version. As of version 1.2.3 this is included by default but for earlier versions you had to explicitly download it. Heres the link:

http://www.siafoo.net/article/62

Direct links to the files:

Core compat file: http://crew.icapsid.net/stou/mootools/mootools-compat-core.js
More compat file: http://crew.icapsid.net/stou/mootools/mootools-compat-more.js

Mootools no longer have these easily available on their site as they would like everyone to upgrade (or an over sight by them) but they do have the original librarys available.

That said Mootools have release and update to their 1.1 and 1.2 version due to a change in Firefox 3.6 thats due for release. Suggest you read the blog post below:

http://mootools.net/blog/2009/11/02/upgrade-mootools/#more-435

Comment: I've been trying to understand and try this links but none of them seems to work for me. Currently I am using 
  mootools-1.1.2-nc.js and mootools.js
and i tried to use 

mootools-1.2.4-core.js
mootools-1.2.4.2-more.js
    
mootools-compat-core.js
mootools-compat-more.js

the menu works but the video is not loaded into the videobox. 

Also adding the Custom Backwards-Compatibility Library found at http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/137 does not work or worse makes the menu also not to work.

Am I applying this in the wrong way. Please help???

Comment: The order that you include the scripts is important. You don't want to include any old versions of mootools at all so delete the 1.1.2 reference completely. You want to include the mootools core and more then the compatability layer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I realised that the import order is important i tried what you are saying
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../menucss/mootools-1.2.4-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menucss/mootools-1.2.4.2-more.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menucss/mootools-compat-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menucss/mootools-compat-more.js"></script>

but my video box shows empty, it was the one using the older version of mootools seems that this solution is not working for me???

Comment: i did say this in the other post - "There is an abstraction layer that brings mootools 1.11 compatibility into 1.2 - check http://www.siafoo.net/article/62," - it still does not mean that what i said is wrong. you can't RUN the two together - you run 1.2.x + compat layer for 1.11.

Comment: I know what you said and I also read the article you are suggesting but nothing seems working for me...

Comment: despite of using the layer, you still need to do certain changes/fixes. it would depend on the code you run - for some things, it will be trivial or no changes. clearly, not the case with you. i suggest using www.mooshell.net to setup a working prototype with the errors though, it would be far easier to help with particular problems and not just theoretical issues

Answer (score 0):

not in a framework that does prototyping, although the differences between 1.11 and 1.2 are seldom to do with prototypes.

please read [Incomatible Mootools scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407659/incomatible-mootools-scripts) - it has already been asked.